# Counting records from database and inserting data into a GridView

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Good morning,

I have been trying to get my mind around doing a simple count of records in an application I am making in visual studio.

The database associated with the application keeps records of people each of them belonging in a certain department. Within the application I want to create a statistics window which counts how many people of each department are currently kept in the database.

In my mind the way to do this would be to select distint values from the department column and then for each result to query again with the count method in order to get a value for each, however I feel this is not the quite correct way to do so.

What I want pretty much is to have a window with a grid view in which the first column holds the name of the department and the second one holds the number of people in that very same department but due to actually beeing new to visual studio and programming in general I couldn't quite figure out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by simple join query in database . try following query :

```
SELECT A.ID , SUM(CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALNOOFPEOPLE
FROM DEPARTMENT AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE AS B ON A.ID = B.DEPARTMENTID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dept]([DeptName] varchar NULL,
    [StudName] varchar NULL)

select DeptName,count(*) as NoOfPeople from [sample].[dbo].[Dept] group by [DeptName]

In windows form

SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter ('select DeptName,count(*) as NoOfPeople from [sample].[dbo].[Dept] group by [DeptName]',con)

DataTable dt=new DataTable();

sda.fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSourc=dt;

dataGridView1.DataBind();